# jQuery .append() not working with jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jQuery File Upload and on success I'm trying to append hidden input field to a form but it is not working, the element is not being appended.

```
jupload.fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '/content/upload',
    done: function (e, data) {
            $("#fileupload").append('<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_files[]">');

        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="create-submit" id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

Comment: what error occur in your functionality ?

Comment: Nothing happens, the element is not appended

Comment: are you get success response from your request ?

Comment: Yes, when I do alert event before append it shows

Comment: $("#fileupload").append('<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_files[]">');
 this code not issue. I try my form. working fine.

Comment: pls find uploaded_files input box in end of your form

Comment: I don't know what is the issue, it is not being shown in the end of the form when I view page source after that event

Comment: Pls could it be the issue of jQuery File Upload plugin?

Comment: @Barba It won't be in the "view page source", as that only shows content that was part of the original request. Try inspecting the DOM itself using the browser's development tools.